# pass dynamic date in execute immediate in PL SQL Block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to pass date to "Create table" statement in PL/SQL Block, because I would like to create snapshot table for last unprocessed day.
I was trying to run following code:

```
DECLARE
  current_date_key NUMBER;
  current_date DATE;
BEGIN
  SELECT date_key
  INTO current_date_key
  FROM tmp_periods per WHERE per.status = 'UNPROCESSED';

  current_date := trunc(TO_DATE(current_date_keys(i), 'yyyymmdd'));
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE tmp_history_snapshot AS SELECT * FROM communication_history WHERE 
  new_date = :1' using current_date;    
END;
```

But it returns ORA-01027 error code.

Can you help me how to pass date to this kind of statement?

Comment: Yes, Aman answer below is the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind variables are not allowed in DDL,
Concatenate instead of using bind variable.

```
DECLARE
  current_date_key NUMBER;
  current_date DATE;
  q VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT date_key
  INTO current_date_key
  FROM tmp_periods per WHERE per.status = 'UNPROCESSED';

  current_date := trunc(TO_DATE(current_date_keys(i), 'yyyymmdd'));

  q := 'CREATE TABLE tmp_history_snapshot AS SELECT * FROM communication_history WHERE
  new_date = ' || current_date;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q;
END;
```

And you better format the date to avoid undesired behavior.